# h2o model not subscriptable

Tags: python, h2o

I think fairly simple question - I'm looking to understand how I can extract various bits of metadata out of a h2o model I built in python?

In R I can run the following to get this sort of information.

```
my_h2o_model@algorithm
my_h2o_model@parameters

my_performance = h2o.performance(my_h2o_model)
my_performance@metrics$thresholds_and_metric_scores # awesome see all classifier metrics at each threshold
```

In python if I try

```
my_h2o_model['algorithm']
```

or

```
my_h2o_model[0]

perf=model_performance(my_h2o_model)
perf['metrics']['thresholds_and_metric_scores] # !!!!
```

> TypeError: 'H2OGradientBoostingEstimator' object is not subscriptable

How can get this information out of the models in python??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used dir() to find the various functions I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo -- you're missing a single quote after `thresholds_and_metric_scores`.

```
perf['metrics']['thresholds_and_metric_scores']
```

Comment: figured it out with the dir() function, but yes - thanks